# Wordpress/Bootstrap 2 anchor linking issue

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am experiencing an issue concerning my social media links inside my wordpress/bootstrap navbar menu.
My one-page wordpress theme is based on bootstrap 2.2.1.
The **header.php** looks like this:

```
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top <?php echo get_option('_dw_page_navbar_class'); ?>" >
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="cart-placement">
                <?php do_action( 'your_theme_header_top' ); ?>
            </div>

            <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar" type="button">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>    

            <div id="test" class="some">
                    <?php do_action('dw_page_socials'); ?>
            </div>
                    <?php dw_page_generate_menu(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>    
</nav>
```

The part of the code in **functions.php** that handles the one-page menu looks like this.

```
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-direction">
<?php  
        foreach ($menu as $menu_item) {
            $active = $i == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '';
            $menu_id = sanitize_title($menu_item->title);
?>
            <?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <li <?php echo $active ?>>
                <a href="#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
            <?php echo $menu_item->title  ?>
                </a>
            </li>          
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php
            $i++;
        }
?>               
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This code is creating the anchor links inside the one-page. So that I am able to create anchor links inside the navbar menu, ex. *www.example.com/#home*, this part works as expected!

The issue occurs when it comes to the social media links, also placed inside the `<nav>` as you can tell from the **header.php**. These links are also affected by the # anchoring, so that i.e a fbook link will look like this *www.example.com/#https://www.facebook.com.*

**How can I remove the # anchoring for the social media links, but keep them for the internal one-page linking?**

Comment: Is this a theme you're developing for a specific client, or for more general use? How do you envision the social media links changing?

Comment: The theme is for general use. I would like the social media links to not contain `www.example.com/#` before the actual URL when being on front page.